# How to fix this "Finding 'android.widget.TextView' using 'CLASS_NAME' with the contextId: '' multiple: false"

Tags: automation, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am testing a hybrid app which has Textview. Iam not able find the elements using classname.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you switch the context before interacting with this element.This is an android native element so your driver context should be set to native